# How Laravel files are copied to public directory using Elixr Gulp

Tags: php, laravel, gulp

I am trying to figure out how copying is working?
e-g in below code

```
elixir(function (mix) {
    mix.sass([
        'app.scss',
        'custom.scss',
        'vendor.scss',
        'theme.scss',
        'utility.scss'
    ])
        .copy(
        mix.bowerDir + '/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
        'public/js/jquery.js'
    )
        .copy(
        mix.bowerDir + '/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
        'public/css/bootstrap.css'
    )
        .copy(
        mix.bowerDir + '/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css',
        'public/css/font-awesome.css'
    )
        .copy(
        mix.bowerDir + '/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js',
        'public/js/jquery-ui.js'
    )
        .copy(
        mix.bowerDir + '/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
        'public/js/bootstrap.js'
    )
        .styles([
            'bootstrap.css',
            'theme.css',
            'utility.css',
            'custom.css'
        ],'public/css/merged.css','public/css');
});
```

i have bootstrap js file included as well as css file included.

But what about the fonts of bootstrap?? they are not copied to public directory?

How is it suppose to work? Should I copy the files manually to public folder or do the same thing like I did for `bootstrap.min.css` for all font files.

Answer (score 1):

Well since you are explicitly copying each file you also have to copy the fonts.

```
.copy(
    mix.bowerDir + '/bootstrap/dist/fonts/**',
    'public/fonts'
)
```

Imho this is the not right way to deal with your assets, I place all my assets inside the public folder. I don't like to copy every asset to my public folder specially if you are using Bower, you'll have to create, one or more, copy rule for each package.

If you are using Bower you should try these two packages, [Laravel-elixir-wiredep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/laravel-elixir-wiredep) for injecting bower packages into your php files and [laravel-elixir-useref](https://www.npmjs.com/package/laravel-elixir-useref) to concat and minify them